# Custom css property with no value

Tags: css

I want to build a custom css property that disable element (instead of using the `disabled` keyword)

So, I wrote the below, but it did not work

```html
<style>
.admin {
    color: green;
    enable: 
}

.user {
    color: red;
    --btn-disable: 0;
}

@property --btn-disable
    {
        syntax: '<number>';
        cursor: not-allowed;
        pointer-events: none;

        /*Button disabled - CSS color class*/
        color: #c0c0c0;
        background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229) !important;

    }

.btn-disabled
    {
        cursor: not-allowed;
        pointer-events: none;

        /*Button disabled - CSS color class*/
        color: #c0c0c0;
        background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229) !important;

    }
</style>
<h1>{{.PageTitle}}</h1>
<ul>
    {{range .Todos}}
            <input class={{.Classes}}>{{.Title}}</li>
    {{end}}
</ul>
```

The above template, will give something like:

```html
<html><head><style>
.admin {
    color: green;
    enable: 
}

.user {
    color: red;
    --btn-disable: 0;
}

@property --btn-disable
    {
        syntax: '<number>';
        cursor: not-allowed;
        pointer-events: none;

         
        color: #c0c0c0;
        background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229) !important;

    }

.btn-disabled
    {
        cursor: not-allowed;
        pointer-events: none;

         
        color: #c0c0c0;
        background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229) !important;

    }
</style>
</head><body><h1>My TODO list</h1>
<ul>
    
            <input class="admin btn-disabled">Task 1
    
            <input class="user">Task 2
    
            <input class="admin user">Task 3
    
</ul>
</body></html>
```

The first input is styled using `.btn-disabled` that is working fine, the second input is styled using `--btn-disabled` and it is not working fine.
The last element is styled using both ways together, but not working as well, most likely as the `--btn-disabled` is the last style implemented.

[image]
Any thought?

Comment: Is there some confusion between HTML and CSS here? disabled is an HTML attribute, --disabled is a CSS property.

Comment: @AHaworth I want to use `--disabled` as CSS property, to avoid confusion, I renamed it as `--btn-disable`

Comment: Thanks, I'd misunderstood. What's the reason for wanting to set a CSS property rather than use a class?

Comment: If the element is `disabled` or not, it depends on another class, like `admin` / `user` / `...` so instead of writing `nested if` statements in my code, I thought it could be more lean to use as sub property or custom property.

Comment: Could you add the relevant HTML and JS? Where is the button in relation to the .admin or .user element?

Comment: @AHaworth kindly see the updated code, notes and screenshoot.

Comment: I can't see much sense in this. Setting `disabled` in HTML, influences the _function_ of the element. It is not CSS' job to do that.

Comment: *I want to build a custom css property that disable element*-- > I think you are miss understanding custom properties. Not sure from where you got the syntax you are using but it doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry, I agree with @CBroe, I can't see the point in trying to use a CSS variable. You can get any styling you want using a combination of classes, but you can't stop some of the functions like HTML attribute disabled can.

Comment: Thanks @AHaworth Can you have a look at my answer and advise your comments.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe Can you have a look at my answer and advise your comments.

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif Can you have a look at my answer and advise your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it using `[data-any="xxx"]`, as below:

```html
<html><head><style>
[data-authorized="no"] {  
   
        cursor: not-allowed;
        pointer-events: none;
         
        color: #c0c0c0;
        background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229) !important;
}
</style>
</head><body><h1>My TODO list</h1>
<ul>
    
            <input type="text" data-authorized="yes">Task 1
    
            <input type="text" data-permissions="user" data-authorized="no">Task 2
    
            <input type="text" data-authorized="yes">Task 3
    
</ul>

<script>
  var flags = ["admin", "super user"]
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll("input");
  elements.forEach((element, index, array) => { 
        if(element.hasAttribute("data-permissions")){
            console.log(element.dataset.permissions)
            var perm = element.dataset.permissions.split(" ");
                    var found = false;
                    for (var i = 0; i < perm.length; i++) {
                        if (flags.indexOf(perm[i]) > -1) {
                            element.dataset.authorized = "yes"
                            element.removeAttribute("data-permissions")
                            break;
                        }
                    } 
        }
  });
</script>
</body></html>
```

Considering the valuable comments on the question, I've to avoid using it in the client side, and start looking now how can I make it in the server side.

[image]